# Azure Container Instance able to run execution scripts via Az CLI from public IP despite VNET only inbound NSG

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-instances, azure-nsg

So I've deployed an Azure Container Instance Group in a private Subnet & VNET where the default inbound rules on the NSG applies.

[image]
There isn't a public IP allocated (as expected) however, I am still able to leverage Azure CLI to execute scripts with the following command from a public IP.

```
az container exec --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myContainer --exec-command /bin/bash
```

Ideally, the NSG inbound rules should have disallowed such invocation outside of the internal VNET IP address range. Likewise, `az container logs` & `az container logs attach` is also able to retrieve the logs from the said container instance. My question is therefore, why? How is it that these inbound calls are not blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because these are not inbound calls. These are calls to Azure REST API, which in turn does something on your behalf. So in essence this is the same as creating a storage account or shutting down virtual machine from the portal. There should be a provider operation, that would be responsible for invoking that action. You can create a deny role assignment (with Azure Blueprints) or craft roles in such a fashion that a user wouldn't have access to that particular action.